# Indesign workflow for hidden text visible only on TOC and running headers

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, workflow

I am working on a storybook with the sections split into two based on two authors. Each of the two sections have multiple stories that each spans a few pages, hence the recto running header will have the story’s name. The authors’ name need to be visible on the verso running header and the table of contents, not anywhere in the content pages.

If I make a box with the author’s name and apply a new style – which will update in the verso running header through text variables – and place the box in the first story of each section, then the TOC updates with the author’s name between the first and second story, *not* before the first story, as it should be.

*Just a extra info in case anyone finds it useful:*

I am new to (and excited with) using primary text frames. I foolishly manually threaded the author box to the first frame of the first story so that TOC problem would get resolved. It did get resolved, but now those text frames are no long the primary. I will need to delete all of them and move the text into new primary text frames after applying the master again.